# Comparison error for quantiles for survival (survfit object)

Tags: r

I am trying to follow a textbook example of survival analysis and am not sure where I'm going wrong here:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame( cbind(seq(1:5),c(6,44,21,14,62),c(1,1,0,1,1)) )
names(df1) <- c('subject','time','censor')
require(survival)
f1 <- survfit(Surv(time=time, event=censor) ~1, data=df1)
quantile(f1)
```

Which gives the following:

```
Error in xi == xj : comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `[.survfit`(x, !nas) :Survfit object has only a single survival curve
2: In `[.survfit`(x, i) : Survfit object has only a single survival curve
3: In `[.survfit`(x, j) : Survfit object has only a single survival curve
```

I have tried this with survfit objects with more than one curve and still get the same message...

"R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)"

"x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

Output from search():

```
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:km.ci"     "package:survival" 
[4] "package:splines"   "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[7] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[10] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Many thanks!

EDIT: thanks DWin and sorry I missed that in `help(Surv)`.

However I'm still getting the same error message.
I'm reading the help for:
`quantile.survfit {survival}` which is documented as an S3 generic, so I was expecting that using `quantile(f1)` should invoke this method.

However I'm finding that the following doesn't work:

```
survival:::quantile.survfit(f1)
```

Gives:

```
Error: 'quantile.survfit' is not an exported object from 'namespace:survival'
```

Tried re-installing survival and it's still the most current version: survival_2.36-10

Answer (score 2):

Two concerns I have. In the help page for `Surv` I see this sentence: "The time,time2 and event arguments are matched by position, not by name, so use, eg, `Surv(time, dead)` rather than `Surv(time, event=dead)`". Which solves the first problem I had with your code by dropping the event argument in the call:

```
f1 <- survfit(Surv(time=time, censor) ~1, data=df1)
```

But then I was expecting to find that was a fit object, i.e. a list,  and I was not surprised that `quantile` objected:

```
> quantile(f1)
Error in approx(c(0, 1 - newy), c(0:length(newy)), p) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
```

So did you want:

```
> quantile(f1$time)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   6   14   21   44   62     # ???
```

Edit: Apparently sometime in the intervening 10 years there is now a quantile method for `survfit` objects and you now get.

```
> quantile(f1)
$quantile
25 50 75 
14 44 62 

$lower
25 50 75 
 6 14 44 

$upper
25 50 75 
NA NA NA
```

Comment: What is the correct interpretation of the quantile output e.g. `(25%) = 14`? Does this mean that 75% of the cohort were alive (survived) on day 14? thanks

Comment: It's for predicted mortality and you need to remember that censoring might have occurred which would mean that there might be less than 75% actual survival at 14. (In this case there wasn't but in general that interpretation would need to be adjusted slightly. I was running the code again with the intent of using `str` on the output of `f1` when I discovered that there is now a quantile method for survfit objects and the answer is now out-of-date.